# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'. when starting the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have React Native project and when I try to run using npx react-native run-android I found some errors that said like this
`A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.`

[image: Error RN Vector Icons]

Currently, I'm using `React Native 0.55.4` and `React Native Vector Icons 4.3.0`

I try to re-install using `npm uninstall` and `npm install` again but turns out it's not solving the error. How can I solve this error? at first, I can run my project successfully but suddenly out of nowhere I cannot run it again because of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your gradle version might fix this issue

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work